# Android Studio настройка Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Здравствуйте!
У ComboBox в VS имеются свойства DisplayMember и ValueMember, но у Spinner-а я подобных не обнаружил:( Почитав переполнение стека, я нашел решение с Adapter-ом, но в моем случае оно не подходит. У меня выбираются из БД ID товара и название товара, ID не упорядочены. Помогите пожалуйста организовать DisplayMember и ValueMember у Spinner в Android Studio дабы я мог разместить в ValueMember ID, а в DisplayMember название товара!

Comment: Используйте не строки в качестве отображаемых данных для адаптера спиннера, но модели данных с полями ID и TITLE например. Так у вас все данные будут и вы будете сами контролировать что отображать и что использовать